# Subquery and joins SQL

Tags: sql, oracle, join, count, subquery

I want to find out which manufacturer's vehicles are involved in the highest number of sales
which incur 2 or more product points. And show the manufacturer name and the total number
of sales that the manufacturer’s vehicles are involved in.

```
CREATE TABLE product (
    prod_code          NUMBER(3) NOT NULL,
    prod_description   VARCHAR2(75) NOT NULL,
    prod_points        NUMBER(2) NOT NULL
);

CREATE TABLE product_sale (
        sale_no         NUMBER(8) NOT NULL,
        sale_datetime   DATE NOT NULL,
        sale_location   VARCHAR2(100) NOT NULL,
        prod_code       NUMBER(3) NOT NULL,
        officer_id     NUMBER(8) NOT NULL,
        lic_no   CHAR(10) NOT NULL,
        veh_no  CHAR(17) NOT NULL
    );

CREATE TABLE vehicle (
    veh_no         CHAR(17) NOT NULL,
    veh_manufyr     DATE NOT NULL,
    veh_maincolor   VARCHAR2(20) NOT NULL,
    veh_manufname   VARCHAR2(30) NOT NULL,
    veh_modname     VARCHAR2(20) NOT NULL,
    veh_type        CHAR(2) NOT NULL
);
```

[image]

[image]

I'm not sure about how to correlate 3 different joins and find the output.

Expected Output:

[image]

Comment: Is that sample table data or the expected result? We need both.

Comment: Sample data. Edited with expected output.

Comment: So what's the relationship between VEHICLE and PRODUCT? Or VEHICLE and PRODUCT_SALE?

Comment: @APC probably `vehicle#veh_no` = `product_sale#veh_no` but it's only a guess.

Comment: Sorry. Edited my Question. Vehicle and Product have veh_no common.

Comment: @APC  prod_points > 2 where group by lic_no (select veh_no for these records and sum(count(sale nos)) then find the manufname from veh_no and sum (total sale nos)
Something like this. Output will have the manufacture name and total no of sales.

Comment: So in other words, you need to find all products from `product` table which have 2 or more product_points, then for these products calculate total sales for each  manufacturer, then pick the manufacturer which has a highest sale (but only for these products >=2 points), and then for this one "winner" caclulate all sales (regardless of product points), is that correct ?

Comment: Yes. @krokodilko

Comment: Please clarify via edits, not comments. Please [use text, not images/links, for text--including tables & ERDs](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/285551/3404097). Use images only for what cannot be expressed as text or to augment text. You are not saying what you want. "correlate 3 different joins" doesn't mean anything. Use enough words, sentences & references to parts of examples to clearly & fully say what you mean. When giving a business relation(ship)/association or table (base or query result), say what a row in it states about the business situation in terms of its column values.

Comment: Please in code questions give a [mre]--cut & paste & runnable code, including smallest representative example input as code; desired & actual output (including verbatim error messages); tags & versions; clear specification & explanation. Give the least code you can that is code that you show is OK extended by code that you show is not OK. (Debugging fundamental.) For SQL that includes DBMS & DDL (including constraints & indexes) & input as code formatted as a table. [ask] Show what parts you can do & explain about being stuck & how you are trying to finish.

Answer (score 1):

Something like that ? (not tested)

```
SELECT veh_manufname, total_sales_count
FROM (
   SELECT v.veh_manufname, 
          count(*) as total_sales_count,
          count( CASE WHEN prod_code IN (
                     SELECT prod_code FROM product WHERE prod_points >= 2
                ) THEN 1 END ) as sales_point_2
   FROM product_sale p
   JOIN vehicle v ON v.veh_no = p.veh_no
   GROUP BY v.veh_manufname
)
ORDER BY sales_point_2 DESC
LIMIT 1
-- LIMIT 1 works on most databases: MySql, PostgreSql, SQLite ....
-- If you are using ORACLE then remove the above line and uncomment the below one
-- FETCH 1 ROWS ONLY

-- If you are using SQL Server then (probably) SELECT TOP 1 will work but I'am not sure
```

Comment: Also if there is more than one manufacturer with the same total, sort them by manufacturer name in ascending format. How do I get this?